# Даты между php и mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

Добрый день!

Почему один и тот же код работает по разному в php и ms studio?

```
select date_end from reports where date_end <='01.07.2017'
```

В php дату понимает как 7 января, а в ms studio как 1 июля

Comment: так бывает ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: локаль, вероятно, разная.

Comment: Тип в базе: datetime2. Ну так тут и козе понятно что день с месяцем путаются. Почему? Как исправить?

Comment: Проще всего прибить гвоздями - `to_char(date_end, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2017-07-01'`. Красивее - всюду установить один и тот же формат при конвертировании по-умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

используйте формат даты yyyy-mm-dd в запросе

`select date_end from reports where date_end <='2017-07-01'`

Comment: А где у вас формат даты в запросе?

Comment: имеется в виду, передавать в запросе дату в формате YYYY-MM-DD, выше код приведен

Comment: Откуда известно, что поле `date_end` в том же формате?